# Visual Studio - quick key or snippet for <% %>

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, code-snippets

My goal is to be able to quickly type this:

```
<%= %>
```

Can anyone suggest a way to make it easier within Visual Studio to insert the HTML code escape block. (I am not even sure the name of this piece of code!)

I realize that typing `<%` in the code editor will autocomplete the escape block for me, but perhaps there's an easier way to input this block?

Perhaps there is a snippet or existing key combo built into Visual Studio to accomplish this?

Even further, this would be nice as well:

```
<%= Html.Encode() %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but it looks like snippets are not available for ASP.Net markup.

From this [guy](http://blog.einbu.no/2009/04/whats-so-cool-about-code-snippets/)

> Snippets are in VS2008 available for
>   C#, XML and VB.NET files. In VS2010
>   that support extends to ASP.NET markup
>   also.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you created a snippet to do that, given VS does automatic matching, wouldnt it be more keystrokes to enter the snippet, than to actually type the 3 characters?

Comment: this is a fair point, and certainly my goal is to reduce the number of keystrokes.

Comment: best case you could write a macro for it and assign it to a single ctrl-key chord.... but still..

Answer (score 1):

Create a snippet and use Ctrl-K, Ctrl-X(VS 2005) and that will let you select the snippet!

Comment: The "Insert Snippet" command is not available in *.aspx files. Note, not everyone has the shortcut key bound to that command.